# How to 'GetMethod' on multiple function definitions where match has generic parameter type?

Tags: .net, generics, reflection

I need to invoke a method on a class using reflection. The class contains two overloads for the same function:

```
    string GenerateOutput<TModel>(TModel model);
    string GenerateOutput<TModel>(TModel model, string templateName);
```

I'm getting the method like so:

```
    Type type = typeof(MySolution.MyType);
    MethodInfo method = typeof(MyClass).GetMethod("GenerateOutput", new Type[] {type ,typeof(string)});
    MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(type);
```

The method is not fetched (`method = null`), I guess because the first method parameter is a generic type. How should this be handled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two possible issues - finding a method if it is non-public (the example shows non-public), and handling the generics.

IMO, this is the easiest option here:

```
MethodInfo generic = typeof(MyClass).GetMethods(
        BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
    .Single(x => x.Name == "GenerateOutput" && x.GetParameters().Length == 2)
    .MakeGenericMethod(type);
```

You could make the `Single` clause more restrictive if it is ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

In .NET, when working with generics and reflection, you need to provide how many generic parameters has a class or method like so:

```
"NameOfMember`N"
```

Where "N" is generic parameters' count.

Comment: except that returns `null` for `method`

Comment: Thanks for that point. I've edited it as it could be good enough as an advise for him :)

Comment: I forgot to say I've removed code sample because as I don't know actual code, I don't want to invent what's behind his problem.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. Marc's solution however is nicer as I don't like to write IL code.

Comment: Are you sure this is about IL?